# JedisPool Connection Refused Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a small spring boot application that I am trying to integrate with Redis using Jedis client.

I set up the Jedis pool to point towards a Redis docker container running locally.

```
    @Bean
public JedisPool jedisPool() {
    JedisPool jedisPool = null;
    try {
        URI redisUri = new URI("redis://localhost:6379");
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig(), redisUri, 20000, null, null, null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to create the redis pool: ", e);
    }
    return jedisPool;
}
```

I have a `RedisService` that makes use of the `JedisPool` and perform transactions against the  Redis Server.

```
 @Autowired
JedisPool jedisPool;

@Override
public String retrieve(String key) {
    Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
    String json = jedis.get(key);
    jedis.close();
    return json;
}

@Override
public void store(String key, String value) {
    Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
    jedis.set(key, value);
    jedis.expire(key, keyExpire);
    jedis.close();
}
```

When running the app I get this exception

`redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool`

`Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

I am able to connect to the Redis Server via `redis-cli` but not from my spring boot app.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://localhost:6379 instead your current URI

Comment: same thrown exception